# Discord.js level system not leveling up as XP keeps going

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

Coding a discord.js bot using WOK's tutorials, made a basic leveling system, I will add more features to it in the future, and the code is working mostly, except that the level doesn't update when the XP reaches the right value. Every message takes up 10 XP and the amount of XP needed to level up is (level number * 100) e.g. level 1->2 = 100, level 2->3 = 200 etc.

The code works and doesn't return any errors until when I type a certain amount of messages that should get me to the next level, i get this error: `drainWaitQueue(topology[kWaitQueue], new MongoError('Topology is closed, please connect'));`

And the level-up message from the bot doesn't send and the mongo database just keeps adding XP instead of resetting it to 0 and adding 1 level.

Here is my code:

```
const mongo = require('./mongo')
const profileSchema = require('./schemas/profile-schema')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('message', (message) => {
        const { guild, member } = message

        addXP(guild.id, member.id, 10, message)
    })
}

const getNeededXP = level => level * 100

const addXP = async (guildId, userId, xpToAdd, message) => {
    await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            const result = await profileSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                guildId,
                userId,
            }, {
                guildId,
                userId,
                $inc: {
                    xp: xpToAdd,
                },
            }, {
                upsert: true,
                new: true,
            })

            let { xp, level } = result
            const needed = getNeededXP(level)

            if (xp >= needed) {
                ++level
                xp -= needed

                const levelUpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('**NEW LEVEL REACHED**')
                .setDescription(`You are now level ${level} with ${xp} experience! You now need ${getNeededXP(level)} XP to reach the next level!`)
                message.channel.send()

                await profileSchema.updateOne({
                    guildId,
                    userId
                }, {
                    level,
                    xp
                })
            }
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
    })
}

module.exports.addXP = addXP
```

Here is the schema for the mongo database, which also includes a coins amount for an economy system (the economy system works perfectly fine):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const reqString = {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

const profileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    guildId: reqString,
    userId: reqString,
    coins: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    xp: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    level: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1,
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('profiles', profileSchema)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Your code doesn’t look well-structured. Firstly, where do you connect to mongodb? Secondly, anonymous functions must be declared before usage (At addXP).

Comment: I connect to mongo in a separate file the i imported at the top line, that has no issues, where and how should I declare the anonymous function? Because I had a problem earlier and someone on discord told me to use an anonymous function, and I'm not sure how they work.